# Error on load and loadXML using DOM

Tags: php, xml, xslt, load, xslt-1.0

I am trying to load an XML file but I get the following errors either I use load(''); or loadXML(); I guess the error is somewhere not in the load, but I can not think what may be. What am I missing here?

**the XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="files">
        <xsl:variable name="docs">
            <docs>
                <xsl:for-each select="file">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </docs>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($docs)"/>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
  <product>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </product>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I think you're mixing two things here: The error you state for `load` is clearly a `loadXml` error, which is comprehensible as `loadXml` expects xml as a string, and if you put a file path here you'll get that error. The second just seems like everything worked (on the loading) but you have errors in your xslt file. (please post the xslt file, too)

Comment: @Yoshi @Gordon I have updated the question with my XSLT.

Comment: It might be just me, but shouldn't `$xslt = new DomDocument;` be `$xslt = new DomDocument();` ?

Comment: @Nanne No, if no constructor parameters are needed and you don't wont to pass optional ones, leaving the `()` is ok.

Comment: @Yoshi: thanks :). I do think it's rather less readable, but that doesn't matter here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary of my comments (now deleted):

While I dont see any `loadXML` in your example code, the first error message tells you the XML you tried to load is malformed because of what it says. Like Yoshi pointed out, you might be trying to load a URI when `loadXML` expects an XML String.

The second error message implies that you are using an unknown function in the XPath select expression. [libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/)/[libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/) only supports XPath 1.0. `msxsl:node-set($docs)` is not a regular xpath function. its not supported.

Try without the namespace, e.g. just `node-set`. If that doesnt work, replace the msxsl namespace with `xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"` in the root element and try with `exsl:node-set`.

Also see [Understanding the node-set() Function](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html)

Comment: I have used the namespace you suggested me and it is working, thanks! So the error was in my xslt.